# Dovecot configuration issue: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate, dovecot, openssl, imap

I've set up a test server per the tutorial on https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/

The problem is in trying to login with Thunderbird (or any client).  Thunderbird complains it can't find the settings for my email account.  Here's the dovecot log with debug on.

```
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file /etc/dovecot/passwd.db: Read 3 users in 0 secs
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=4148)
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=4150)
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=4151)
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=4152)
Mar  9 11:44:30 mydomain dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.0.218.2, lip=172.31
```

Here is my dovecot config

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-66-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS ext4
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
mail_home = /var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n/mail:LAYOUT=fs
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = username_format=%u scheme=ssha512 /etc/dovecot/passwd.db
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_after = /var/mail/vmail/sieve-after
  sieve_before = /var/mail/vmail/sieve-before
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = imap sieve
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol lda {
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster@mydomain.com
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = tb-extra-mailbox-sep
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}
```

I had an earlier problem with my certificate (I had self-signed it) - but Thunderbird happily accepted it after I added an exception.

I am able to access my mailserver remotely with telnet.

```
openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:143 -starttls imap
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

From here I can login to my account and see inbox.

I can also connect to port 993 and login.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mail.mydomain.com:993
```

But Thunderbird keeps telling me that my it 'failed to find settings for your server'.  Also messages sent to the server from gmail also fail.

Advice?

Comment: So you configure Thunderbird manually.